# Python почему не работает разделитель в str.join()

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, join

Почему не работает разделитель '\n'.join(), элементы списка выводятся в файл.txt подряд один за одним, без пробела. А должен каждый элемент списка начинаться с новой строки. Когда я удаляю теги, все работает.

```
tx1 = text1.toPlainText()
tx2 = text2.toPlainText()
rows1 = tx1.split('\n')
rows2 = tx2.split('\n')
for i in range(min_len):
   if rows1[i] != rows2[i]:
      str1='<span style="background:#99FF66">'+rows1[i]+'</span>'
      str2='<span style="background:red">'+rows2[i]+'</span>'            
      rows1[i] = str1
      rows2[i] = str2
      txt1 = '\n'.join([str(j) for j in rows1])
      txt2 = '\n'.join([str(j) for j in rows2])
 text1.setText(txt1)
 text2.setText(txt2)
```

Comment: Приведите пример исходных файлов, откуда вы берете текст, потому что, например, у меня нормально работает, если засунуть в `tx1` и `tx2` собственный текст. Возможно, ваш текстовый редактор не воспринимает `\n` как перенос строки, попробуйте `\r\n`, или откройте в другом редакторе.

Comment: Проверил с разными, любыми файлами *.txt. Ни с одним не работает.  '\r\n' тоже не видит. Когда пишу: ' "\n" '.join, между элементами списка появляется: " ".

Comment: А что за `toPlainText` и `setText`? Может проблема в них, потому что если открывать файлы обычным и читать/записывать стандартными питоновскими функциями, проблем нет.

Comment: text1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(txt, parent) - многострочное текстовое поле Gui pyqt4.     text1.setText - наполнить это поле текстом.     text1.toPlainText - получить текст, который уже загруженный в это текстовое поле. Да, с стандартными функциями проблем нет. Пока что только с этим полем.

Comment: а если тогда каждую строку добавлять по отдельности? что то типа такого: `for i in rows1: text1.append(str(i))`

Comment: Flowneee, если добавлять строки из rows через append() - все работает. Спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

**Перенесено из комментариев**

Добавляйте каждую строку в TextEdit по отдельности, используя метод [append](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#append):

```
for i in rows1:
    text1.append(str(i))
```

И аналогично для 2го списка строк.